# magento2 creating a lot of catalogrule_product_temp tables

Tags: database, magento2.2.2

Magento2.2.5 based multisite (multi store view)seems to be creating a lot of temporary tables such as

```
catalogrule_product__temp9a310576
catalogrule_product__temp998786f4
etc...
```

However I am not sure why these tables are being created they all seem to be empty?

Comment: even i am also facing the same issue. Mostly happening during re-indexing.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have yet to see anyone respond with an answer :(

Answer (score 3):

We have been seeing this issue as well. Until a solution is found I am using the following to clear the tables - we've not yet had any issues by removing them.

Add the following to `bin/remove-temp-tables.php`

```
<?php
$settings = require(__DIR__.'/../app/etc/env.php');
$database = $settings['db']['connection']['default'];

$conn = new mysqli($database['host'], $database['username'], $database['password'], $database['dbname']);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$tempName = 'catalogrule_product__temp';

$query = $conn->query('SHOW TABLES FROM `'.$database['dbname'].'`');
$tablesToDelete = [];

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tableName = array_shift($row);
    if (substr($tableName, 0, strlen($tempName)) === $tempName)
        $tablesToDelete[] = $tableName;
}

foreach($tablesToDelete AS $tableName) {
    $conn->query('DROP TABLE `'.$tableName.'`;');
}

echo 'Completed.'.PHP_EOL;
```

Run with `php bin/remove-temp-tables.php`

Comment: Thank you, I used the workaround and its also working for me.

Answer (score 3):

These tables get created by the Catalog Rule indexer. When this indexer fails (=throws an exception) the created table doesn't get cleaned up.
One can use following mysql query to perform a manual cleanup:
(make sure to replace `%DATABASENAME%` by your db name)

```
-- Set up variable to delete ALL tables starting with 'catalogrule_product__temp'
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=1000000;
SET @tbls = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
             FROM information_schema.TABLES
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '%DATABASENAME%'
               AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'catalogrule_product__temp%');
SET @delStmt = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',  @tbls);
-- SELECT @delStmt;
PREPARE stmt FROM @delStmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Its working fine. Thank you.

Comment: I ran the SQL above, and the setup:upgrade command has gone from taking more than 10 minutes to about 30 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue will be fixed in version 2.4
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/27012

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues, did you find a solution? Is it safe to just delete those tables? My database is getting huge and it's getting more and more difficult to make a backup...

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after migrating from Magento 1.9 to 2.3.5 and managed to solve it.

The issue is caused by the reindexing process not being able to finish it's task. So basically when ever you run `php bin/magento cron:run` or `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` you will get an additional temp table which is not being cleaned up.

In my case, the issues was caused by the **CLI** php version. I used php 7.3 when calling cron, but this raised some errors during the reindex process, so I switched to using php 7.1 when calling `cron:run` or `indexer:reindex`.

For Ubuntu, you can try using `/usr/bin/php7.1 bin/magento cron:run`.

The correct php version will vary depending on your Magento 2 version (older Magento versions will require older php versions for running cron jobs).

If you don't have access to your hosting server via SSH, you will need to ask your hosting provider to set this up.